# XCode - Voice recording and saving into NSBundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am developing this application on the iPad.
I want to have this function whereby the user is able to record their voice and it will be saved into the NSBundle.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

As always, the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2) is a great place to start. In the previous link, look for the section titled **Recording with the AVAudioRecorder Class**.

Answer (score 3):

You can't save into your app's NSBundle.  Your app's NSBundle is read-only and cryptographically signed to prevent tampering.

You can save to the app's documents directory though.

Answer (score 1):

And to complet sosborn answer I would add that in the Appel Developer website you have access to a lot of `tech talk from WWDC of 2011 and 2010` as well as some from 2009 shown under the label iOS essential or something like that. There is some about audio on iOS device that are pretty good.